# PHP Form data not stored when submitted?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am working on an synonym/alias manager database where the user has the ability to store an association they feel is right. Say the user types in "rabbit" and no synonyms or aliases are found. The user then decides to associate "rabbit" with "bunny" and stores that into a database. Anytime any other user types in "bunny" the results for "rabbit" will appear. However, I am trying to implement a polling system asking the user if they feel the association is correct. If they think "bunny" fits "rabbit" then they vote yes, otherwise no. This is where I am stuck. As soon as I load the poll and press submit everything disappears and nothing gets sent to the database. Code is below:

```
$query = "SELECT * from searchtestdb where engname in ( SELECT synonyms.synonym  FROM words  LEFT JOIN synonyms ON synonyms.word_id = words.word_id WHERE word LIKE '%$searchBox%') "; // Query for animals in db
        $query = mysql_query($query);

        if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0)
        {
            echo "<h2>Aliases: </h2>";
            echo "Sorry, but we can not find an alias to match your query.";
            echo "<br> ";

        }
        else        
        {
            echo "<h2> Results using Alias: </h2>";
            while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
            {
                $query2 = "SELECT * from searchtestdb where engname LIKE '%".$result['engname']."%';";
                $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
                {
                    print "<h4>Latin Name: </h4> ";
                    echo $row["latname"];
                    echo "<br> "; 
                    print"<h4>English Name:</h4> ";
                    echo $row["engname"];
                    echo "<br>"; 
                    print "<h4> Species: </h4> ";
                    echo $row["spectype"];
                    print "<h4>Characteristics: </h4> ";
                    echo $row["charc1"];
                    echo "<br>"; 
                    echo $row["charc2"];
                    echo "<br>"; 
                    echo $row["charc3"];
                    echo "<br>"; 

                }

            }
            $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
            print "<form method='post' action='$self' >\n";
            print "<h4>Alias Association Correct? : </h4>";
            print "<p>" . 
                  "<input type='radio' name='vote' id='vote' value='1' /> \n" .
                  "Yes" .
                  "<input type='radio' name='vote' id='vote' value='2' /> \n" .
                  "No" .
                  "</p> \n" .
                  "<p>" .
                  "<input type='submit'name='submitVote' value='Submit' />" .
                  "\n </p> \n" .
                  "</form> \n" .
                  $vote=htmlentities($_POST['vote']);
                  echo $vote;

            mysql_connect(----------------------) or die(mysql_error()); 
            mysql_select_db("-----------") or die(mysql_error());       

            if($vote == 1)
            { 
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO items(yes, uNo, word_id) VALUES ('0', '0', bunny');");
                mysql_query("UPDATE items SET yes=yes+1 WHERE word_id='bunny';"); 
                echo 'Thanks for voting Yes!'; 
            } 
            if($vote == 2)
            {   mysql_query("INSERT INTO items(word_id) VALUES ('".$result['engname']."'') ");
                mysql_query("UPDATE items SET uNo=Uno+1 WHERE word_id='".$result['engname']."'");
                echo "changos";
            }

        }
```

Comment: Start with http://php.net/pdo (http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases) and then debug.

Comment: mysql_* are deprecated and will be removed, you should use mysqli_* or pdo in your code.

Comment: trying to fetch result before connecting to database ??

Comment: You should use html_entities on PHP_SELF as it is vulnerable to XSS attacks. So <?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?> is safe.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell I made a small mistake:

```
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

should be

```
$self = $_SERVER['POST'];
```

Thanks Anyway.